# Kotlin execution environment

Tags: android, kotlin

Since Kotlin run on JVM and compiles to Java bytecode, can we say that the Kotlin app in Android and Java app in Android have same execution environment?

Comment: For people down voting: please just add a comment, so that Vincent could learn why his question is not suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that code written in the two languages is processed and executed is completely identical after the initial step when the Kotlin and Java sources are compiled to bytecode by `kotlinc` and `javac`, respectively. After that point, you just have `.class` files which are all handled the same way going forward, through the dexing process all the way to the eventual execution by the virtual machine on device.

If you yourself looked at the bytecode, you could probably tell which original source language a given class was compiled from based on certain characteristic structures and metadata, but the tools processing them further won't care, because they're already in the common format that they can use.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One more thing, the android java app uses ART, is it also same for Kotlin? i am a noob and really confused :)

Comment: Yes, by the point the code ends up in an APK and is installed on the device, the output of the Java and Kotlin sources has long been merged. ART executes the code from both sources, because they all end up in the same .dex files.